# Where I can parse IoT data in Azure so I can afterwards save it to SQL DB

Tags: json, azure, parsing, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm working on some IoT integrations and I am wondering where in the Azure I can parse my IoT data (JSON data).

My earlier workflow was this; sensor pushes data -> iot hub -> stream analytics jobs -> sql database. Stream analytics job works fine but I have heard that it is not "right" way to parse data in Azure. So what is the right and best way to do that. I need to save it to SQL database.

Answer (score 2):

Stream Analytics jobs are perfect for setting up real time analytics on your data.

As an alternative, you can also use databricks and [Structured Streaming](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/structured-streaming-azure-databricks-from-iothub-cosmos-bergere/).

If you do not have a real time requirement, consider using Azure Functions ([Processing data from IoT Hub with Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/)). If you were using Event Hubs, you could use [Event Hubs Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) to move your data in to a storage account and then process further using Azure Data Factory, databricks, or any other technology that can connect to the storage account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The data needs to be real time because I have IoT sensor which basically calculates how many people are in the room and sends that data to iot hub. So is there any other/better way to do that than stream analytics job?

Comment: I would agree with Murray. Stream Analytics is a very good fit for this job. Where did you hear that it's not the right way? If you need more customizable options, Spark Streaming on Azure Databricks is also an alternative - but it includes much more coding and management for you

Comment: You can use Structured Streaming with databricks as an alternative - I have updated my answer with a link.

Comment: Thank you! This gave me more belief to continue with stream analytics job.